# Google Analytics API to get all the data of analytics dashboard

Tags: api, google-analytics, analytics, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-4

Are there any APIs or documentation to get all the data from the google analytics dashboard?

Answer (score 0):

You might to look at the native integration with BigQuery that allows you to *"export all of your raw events from Google Analytics 4 properties (including subproperties and roll-up properties)"*:
Links:

- https://developers.google.com/analytics/bigquery
- https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/9358801?hl=en&ref_topic=9359001&sjid=148541274474202716-EU

Comment: Thanks! Now, I am hitting analytics API through Postman but I got an error as 401:unauthorized or status as unauthenticated the API request is as follows
https://analyticsreporting.googleapis.com/v4/reports:batchGet
{
  "reportRequests":[
  {
    "viewId": view_id,
    "dateRanges":[
    {
      "startDate":"2023-05-01",
      "endDate":"2023-05-23"
    }],
    "metrics":[
    {
      "expression":"ga:users"
    }],
    "dimensions": [
    {
      "name":"ga:pagePath"
    }]
  }]
}

Comment: Kindly upvote the answer if you have found useful. As for the error you are facing, I would suggest opening a new question as a) it is a different topic, b) it would require details on your API call payload, headers etc.